# BreezeSharp: is it possible to use server side POCO model on the client side?

Tags: c#, client, entity, breeze, breeze-sharp

I'm trying out Breeze Sharp for a new WPF app I'm building. I was wondering if there's any way to generate the client side entity from the EF6 Code First Entity.

It would be a showstopper if we had to hand code the client models and keep the client/server entities in sync manually.

Also, I see BreezeJS is quite popular and has a lot of info on the web but BreezeSharp has limited info. Is BreezeSharp a good option for enterprise application? My application will be data heavy and will have a lot of attributes in the entities.

**Update 1:** I tried to use the server side model project on the client and got the following error:

Metadata errors encountered: 
Metadata mismatch classification: 'Missing CLR Entity Type' - for StructuralType: 'XXX...'

Hope someone here can shed some light..

Comment: Anyone? Will be great if someone can reply..

Comment: We couldn't find a good solution, so we manually created another set of entities. You could look into T4 templates, maybe you can get them to work for you. Complexity of our model didn't allow us to do so.

Comment: just wanted to point, it's from their site: "The Breeze.net server components support EF 4.x and 5.x but not EF 6 (which has not been released) nor versions prior to v.4.2". also i can't see any updates in their repository. i wanted to use breeze but looks like i will not.. what about you? did you and up using it or rejected it in the end?

Comment: It does support EF6. In fact, that's what I'm using. they have a separate nuget package for each EF version (see below). I'm using breeze sharp and breeze server for my project and so far its been working pretty good. Really like how you can be hands-off with data persistence.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6/

Answer (score 0):

Use partial classes as descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312552). More infos see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24129958). Both answers are from people working on Breeze.